# Field 'id' doesn't have a default value because of generated value

Tags: java, spring-boot

My entities

FoodItem.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Table(name = "food_items", schema = "restaurant-service")
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class FoodItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    String name;

    BigDecimal price;

    Long restaurant_id;

}
```

Restaurant.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Table(name = "restaurant", schema = "restaurant-service")
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    String name;

    String address;

    BigDecimal priceForDelivery;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id")
    List<FoodItem> menu;
}
```

Controller

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/restaurant/{restaurantId}/item")
    public void createRestaurant(@PathVariable(value = "restaurantId")Long restaurantId,
                                 @RequestBody FoodItem foodItemRequest) {
        repository.findById(id).map(restaurant -> restaurant.getMenu().add(foodItemRequest));
    FoodItem foodItem = FoodItem.builder()
            .name(foodItemRequest.getName())
            .price(foodItemRequest.getPrice())
            .restaurant_id(id)
            .build();
    foodItemRepository.save(foodItem);
    }
```

I just need to save food item in controller without posting an ID, I need that id will be generated without me

I tried to change strategy to the AUTO but it still didn't work

Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
2022-12-06 15:31:31.202 ERROR 39652 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3885) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy98.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy98.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:666) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy101.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.lidapopova.restarauntservice.service.RestaurantService.addFoodItem(RestaurantService.java:73) ~[classes/:na]
at com.lidapopova.restarauntservice.controller.RestaurantController.createRestaurant(RestaurantController.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: How did you create the tables?

Comment: show the table creation query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MySQL table must support IDENTITY primary key generation strategy you must create the primary key with auto_increment.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

IDENTITY means that the database will take care of the generation of the primary key.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot! Thanks a lot!!